# Mac OS X Update 10.6.8 weird phishing behaviour

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts, mac-app-store, phishing

I just updated to Mac App Store 1.0.2 with the update to 10.6.8.

The Mac App Store said I have one update available, for Angry Birds....

I do not have Angry Birds on my system, but when I clicked the update button I got the following message.

> "You have updates available for other
>   accounts.   Sign in to
>   asdfff2011@mail.ru to update
>   applications for that account."

Needless to say this account does not exist. Any ideas what this is all about?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of this?

Answer (score 3):

**Don't download pirated copies of Final Cut Pro X!** (or any software for that matter).

Searching Google for that email address finds a comment thread for a Final Cut Pro X torrent on a popular BitTorrent site with comments like the following:

> But one issue, my Mac App Store now won't let me update or download apps with my account as everytime I try to do so, it tells me to
>
> "Sign in to asdfff2011@mail.ru to update applications for that account."
>
> Could anyone help me get rid of this and get my App Store and Apple ID account back to normal please?? :/

---

> Has anybody solved the 'asdfff2011@mail.ru' Mac App Store problem yet?

---

> I now can't use the App Store without logging in to 'asdfff2011@mail.ru' account! Any fix??
> I'm assuming the user's id is encrypted into that replacement file and needs updating to our unique ID??

Answer (score 2):

Vlueboy is quit correct. Your message suggests that Angry Birds has been installed circumventing the app store. Do other people have access to your Mac? Angry Birds will probably been in their user applications folder instead of the main one.

Unfortunately when software is installed in this manner you are unable to update etc. So you will constantly be reminded about the update unless the app is removed.

I found that it was due to a pirate copy of Final Cut X that was installed . I removed the copy and its preference files and also the file from application support. Now my appstore is back to normal

Answer (score 0):

Considering that MacOS systems have relatively few exploits and are only very recently known to have trojan horse software, it is unlikely that someone made purchases from your computer leaving a trail back to you.

The timing of your question and this [random web post from a couple days ago](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/06/23/mac-os-x-10-6-8-now-available-for-your-downloading-pleasure/#aolc=A2ktkQ) quoting the same e-mail address in a different site could mean you're the same affected fellow. The 1 single reply the person got is that there indeed is software on your computer that the new MacOS has found to "belong" to that particular ID.

From a screenshot in another website, your error message looks a little different for what other users see, because theirs aren't [mentioning a specific e-mail address](http://doronkatz.com/xcode-you-have-updates-available-for-other-ac). Having unwanted things in one's computer is common these days of mega-downloading. I would search for both "Angry Birds" and "asdfff2011@mail.ru" using your magnifying glass tool on the top right (Spotlight) and see if something does come up. You of course can't know the password to review past App store purchases for that other mail.ru (Russian) person, but it is likely that they somehow hacked it to avoid paying, and registered under this seemingly fake address, and somehow you got that one "altered" copy of the software. I'd just ignore it.